# Cannot find module 'webpack/schemas/webpackOptions.json'

Tags: webpack

I am trying to use webpack and I got this error when I want to bundle js files.
I have unistalled webpack and installed it again, but it didn't worked.
What should I do??!

Answer (score 4):

I got this same error while trying to run webpack-dev-server. Turns out that version 3.x of webpack-dev-server is only working with webpack 4.x.

If you use webpack 3.x with webpack-dev-server 3.x, you'll get that error.

So check the versions that are installed and make sure they're compatible.

For example, this combination works for me:

- webpack 3.11.0
- webpack-dev-server 2.11.2

Comment: I'm using latest version.

Comment: What version of webpack and webpack-dev-server do you have?

Comment: I don't know, Because when I trying to see that with "webpack -v" I got this error.

Comment: It would be helpful to specify what version number you used from `webpack-dev-server 2.x` which worked if you could

Comment: @KevinDanikowski , I'm currently using webpack 3.11.0 with webpack-dev-server 2.11.2

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
npm i -g npx
```

After that completes successfully try:

```
npx webpack -w
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Going off @Whyves :

Run `npm install --save-dev webpack-dev-server@"<3.0.0"` to get latest 2.* version which appears to be 2.11.2.